# Python subprocess.checkoutput Called Process Error

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

In the windows command line, I enter the follow command to enable a windows feature:

```
>dism.exe -online -Enable-Feature -FeatureName:MSMQ-HTTP
```

This command works just fine and enables the MSMQ-HTTP feature. Now I'm writing a Python script to automate this process, my code

```
subprocess.check_output(['dism.exe', '-online', '-Enable-Feature', '-FeatureName:MSMQ-HTTP'], shell=True)
```

returns a nasty error, CalledProcessError: Command '['dism.exe', '-online', '-Enable-Feature', '-FeatureName:MSMQ-HTTP']' returned non-zero exit status 11.

Can anyone shed some light as to why this isn't working?

Comment: I normally don't pass a list if I'm going to use `shell=True`, but I don't know how this stuff works on Windows ...

Comment: Also, when called from the commandline, can you verify that the program's exit code is `0`?

Comment: I tried both shell=False and removing that argument altogether, and yes I just verified the exit code as 0 using echo %ERRORLEVEL%

Comment: @mgilson: On Windows, [this](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#converting-an-argument-sequence-to-a-string-on-windows) is how it works both with and without `shell=True`. And it's very easy to get stuff wrong when there are quotes involved, but I don't think it'll matter here.

Comment: First, why are you using `-` parameters instead of `/` parameters? The documentation, and every tutorial I can find, uses `/`. (It's not likely that this is the problem, but there are some programs that check if the parent is cmd.exe, or more generally that it's a console program, and handle parameters differently.)

Comment: Also, have you tried using a string instead of a list (with and without `shell=True`), as mgilson suggested?

Comment: Finally, your cmd example enables "MSMQ-HTTP", while your Python example enables "MSMQ-ADIntegration". Maybe it's just that the former succeeds and the latter fails, and has nothing to do with the way you're calling it. Have you tested swapping each one?

Comment: I was using / earlier, I thought there might be an issue with escape characters so I used - instead. Both produce the same result when run in the command line. I'll try using 1 string instead of a list in a second. The MSMQ-HTTP vs MSMQ-ADIntegration was a typo, I'm enabling several Windows features (such as those 2), I just included the code for one of them since the rest are almost identical.

Comment: Just tried using a string instead of a list, I get non-zero exit status 1 when I have shell=True, and when I have shell=False or remove shell=X, I get WindowsError:[Error 2] System cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Specify absolute path for `dism.exe`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some bitness issues going on with Python's subprocess module and DISM.exe. Even when specifying the C:\Windows\system32\dism.exe absolute path I was getting Error Code 11.

My eventual solution was to write a 10 line batch file:

```
@echo off
if EXIST %WINDIR%\system32\dism.exe ( 
  set DISM=%WINDIR%\system32\dism.exe 
) 
if EXIST %WINDIR%\SysNative\dism.exe ( 
  set DISM=%WINDIR%\SysNative\dism.exe 
)
%DISM% -online -Enable-Feature -FeatureName:MSMQ-ADIntegration
%DISM% -online -Enable-Feature -FeatureName:MSMQ-HTTP
%DISM% -online -Enable-Feature -FeatureName:MSMQ-Triggers
```

This little batch file is called from my Python script via subprocess:

```
def MSMQ():
    p = subprocess.Popen(r"PrereqInstall\SetMSMQFeatures.bat", shell=True)
    stout, stderr = p.communicate()
```